# How do I change the shortcuts in mplayer?

Tags: mplayer

I want to change the shortcuts in mplayer. More specifically, I want when I press the RIGHT button to go to the next song in the playlist instead. How can I do that?

Comment: `mplayer` or one of its frontends like `smplayer`?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are talking of `mplayer` itself, according to the man page<sup>1</sup>:

> MPlayer has a fully configurable, command-driven control layer which allows you to control MPlayer using keyboard, mouse, joystick or remote control (with LIRC).  See the `-input` option for ways to customize it.
>
> ...
>
> ```
>  -input <commands>
>           This option can be used to configure certain parts of the input system.  Paths are relative to ~/.mplayer/. Available commands are:  
> ...
>              conf=<filename>
>                   Specify input configuration file other than the default ~/.mplayer/input.conf.  ~/.mplayer/<filename> is assumed if no full path is given.
>              keylist
>                   Prints all keys that can be bound to commands.
>              cmdlist
>                   Prints all commands that can be bound to keys.
> ```

Edit `~/.mplayer/input.conf` and add the following line (using the examples from [the mplayer website](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/control.html)):

```
RIGHT pt_step 1
```

<sup>1</sup> I am not linking to the [Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/mplayer.1.html) because it differs from what I actually have on my system. In particular, for me, `mplayer` options began with a single hyphen and not double hyphens.

Comment: Thanks a lot muru for your answer. However, editing ~/.mplayer/input.conf had no result in mplayer's behaviour. Just one note, that the file was absolutely empty when I opened that.

Comment: @JimBlum Can you try with `mplayer -input conf=~/.mplayer/input.conf` (just in case the default has changed or somehow differs from your setup and mine)?

Comment: I get this message after I execute this command: "Usage:   mplayer [options] [url|path/]filename

Basic options: (complete list in the man page)
 -vo <drv>        select video output driver ('-vo help' for a list)"[...]

Comment: Therefore it seems that the command is not even recognised

Comment: @JimBlum Er, did you try that without specifying a media file name to play? If so, do add a media file. If not, could you check `man mplayer`, what commands does your mplayer support for `-input`?

Comment: For me it works with general settings (/etc/mplayer/input.config) only.