# Bind character keys to command in Mplayer

Tags: mplayer

How can I bind character keys to command? Like binding `RIGHT seek +5` and something like that but with character keys like `a`, `b`, `c` etc.

**UPDATE**

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508180/how-do-i-change-the-shortcuts-in-mplayer) answer (which this question is marked as duplicate to that question) is talking about to configure keybinding like:

```
LEFT seek -5
RIGHT seek +5
```

that I already know. What I'm asking here is not to use <kbd>LEFT</kbd> or <kbd>RIGHT</kbd> as key bindings. I'm asking about using <kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>L</kbd> as key bindings. Which I've tried this:

```
H seek -5
L seek +5
```

and doesn't work. I know that the `mplayer -input keylist` command not listing any character keys as available key. What I'm asking here is: is it possible to bind charater keys to command in Mplayer?

Comment: @Helio updated about my specific question.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is **no**, however you can edit the source code or make a feature request.

- The `mplayer` documentation says this:

  > You can get a full list of supported key names by running `mplayer -input keylist` and a full list of available commands by running `mplayer -input cmdlist`.
- In my computer `mplayer -input keylist` returns this:

  ```
  SPACE
  SHARP
  ENTER
  TAB
  CTRL
  BS
  DEL
  INS
  HOME
  END
  PGUP
  PGDWN
  ESC
  RIGHT
  LEFT
  DOWN
  UP
  F1
  F2
  F3
  F4
  F5
  F6
  F7
  F8
  F9
  F10
  F11
  F12
  KP0
  KP1
  KP2
  KP3
  KP4
  KP5
  KP6
  KP7
  KP8
  KP9
  KP_DEL
  KP_DEC
  KP_INS
  KP_ENTER
  MOUSE_BTN0
  MOUSE_BTN1
  MOUSE_BTN2
  MOUSE_BTN3
  MOUSE_BTN4
  MOUSE_BTN5
  MOUSE_BTN6
  MOUSE_BTN7
  MOUSE_BTN8
  MOUSE_BTN9
  MOUSE_BTN10
  MOUSE_BTN11
  MOUSE_BTN12
  MOUSE_BTN13
  MOUSE_BTN14
  MOUSE_BTN15
  MOUSE_BTN16
  MOUSE_BTN17
  MOUSE_BTN18
  MOUSE_BTN19
  MOUSE_BTN0_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN1_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN2_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN3_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN4_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN5_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN6_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN7_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN8_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN9_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN10_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN11_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN12_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN13_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN14_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN15_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN16_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN17_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN18_DBL
  MOUSE_BTN19_DBL
  JOY_UP
  JOY_DOWN
  JOY_LEFT
  JOY_RIGHT
  JOY_AXIS0_PLUS
  JOY_AXIS0_MINUS
  JOY_AXIS1_PLUS
  JOY_AXIS1_MINUS
  JOY_AXIS2_PLUS
  JOY_AXIS2_MINUS
  JOY_AXIS3_PLUS
  JOY_AXIS3_MINUS
  JOY_AXIS4_PLUS
  JOY_AXIS4_MINUS
  JOY_AXIS5_PLUS
  JOY_AXIS5_MINUS
  JOY_AXIS6_PLUS
  JOY_AXIS6_MINUS
  JOY_AXIS7_PLUS
  JOY_AXIS7_MINUS
  JOY_AXIS8_PLUS
  JOY_AXIS8_MINUS
  JOY_AXIS9_PLUS
  JOY_AXIS9_MINUS
  JOY_BTN0
  JOY_BTN1
  JOY_BTN2
  JOY_BTN3
  JOY_BTN4
  JOY_BTN5
  JOY_BTN6
  JOY_BTN7
  JOY_BTN8
  JOY_BTN9
  AR_PLAY
  AR_PLAY_HOLD
  AR_NEXT
  AR_NEXT_HOLD
  AR_PREV
  AR_PREV_HOLD
  AR_MENU
  AR_MENU_HOLD
  AR_VUP
  AR_VDOWN
  POWER
  MENU
  PLAY
  PAUSE
  PLAYPAUSE
  STOP
  FORWARD
  REWIND
  NEXT
  PREV
  VOLUME_UP
  VOLUME_DOWN
  MUTE
  XF86_PAUSE
  XF86_STOP
  XF86_PREV
  XF86_NEXT
  CLOSE_WIN
  ```

Source: http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/control.html

Answer (score 2):

The answer is YES you can. Put you bindings in a file named `~/.mplayer/input.config`. Here is my file dumped out for you (with my personal mods):

```
    ##
    ## MPlayer input control file
    ##
    ## You are able to redefine default keyboard/joystick/mouse/LIRC bindings, or
    ## add new ones here.
    ## See DOCS/tech/slave.txt for possible commands that can be bound.
    ## Also see mplayer -input cmdlist for other possible options.
    ## The file should be placed in the $HOME/.mplayer directory.
    ##
    ## If you wish to unbind a key, use key ignore.
    ## e.g. ENTER ignore
    ##

    RIGHT seek +2
    LEFT seek -2
    DOWN volume -1
    UP volume +1
    PGUP seek 300
    PGDWN seek -300
    m mute
    # switch_audio          # switch audio streams
    + audio_delay 0.100
    = audio_delay 0.100
    - audio_delay -0.100
    [ speed_mult 0.9091 # scale playback speed
    ] speed_mult 1.1
    { speed_mult 0.5
    } speed_mult 2.0
    BS speed_set 1.0    # reset speed to normal
    q quit
    ENTER osd       #pt_step 1 1 (skip to next file (too much for an edge key))
    ESC pause
    p pause
    . frame_step            # advance one frame and pause
    SPACE pause
    HOME pt_up_step 1
    END pt_up_step -1
    > pt_step 1             # skip to next file
    < pt_step -1            #         previous
    INS alt_src_step 1
    DEL alt_src_step -1
    o osd
    I osd_show_property_text "${filename}"     # display filename in osd
    P osd_show_progression
    z sub_delay -0.1        # subtract 100 ms delay from subs
    x sub_delay +0.1        # add
    9 volume -1
    / volume -1
    0 volume 1
    * volume 1
    1 contrast -1
    2 contrast 1
    3 brightness -1
    4 brightness 1
    5 hue -1
    6 hue 1
    7 saturation -1
    8 saturation 1
    ( balance -0.1          # adjust audio balance in favor of left
    ) balance +0.1          #                                  right
d frame_drop
D step_property deinterlace  # toggle deinterlacer, requires -vf yadif or kerndeint
r sub_pos -1            # move subtitles up
t sub_pos +1            #                down
#? sub_step +1      # immediately display next subtitle
#? sub_step -1      #                     previous
#? sub_scale +0.1   # increase subtitle font size
#? sub_scale -0.1   # decrease subtitle font size
f vo_fullscreen
f11 vo_fullscreen   # to match my WinVice mod, both to match FireFox - F11 full screen
T vo_ontop              # toggle video window ontop of other windows
w panscan -0.1          # zoom out with -panscan 0 -fs
e panscan +0.1          #      in
c capturing             # save (and append) file/stream to stream.dump with -capture
s screenshot            # take a png screenshot with -vf screenshot
                        # S will take a png screenshot of every frame

h tv_step_channel 1
l tv_step_channel -1
n tv_step_norm
b tv_step_chanlist

##
## Joystick section
## WARNING: joystick support has to be explicitly enabled at
##          compiletime with --enable-joystick
##

JOY_RIGHT seek 10
JOY_LEFT seek -10
JOY_UP seek 60
JOY_DOWN seek -60
JOY_BTN0 pause
JOY_BTN1 osd
JOY_BTN2 volume 1
JOY_BTN3 volume -1
JOY_BTN4 set_menu main

##
## Apple Remote section
##
## To use OSD menu with Apple Remote, set key AR_MENU to any OSD menu command,
## or just comment out the 'AR_MENU osd' line and uncomment the line after it.
##

AR_PLAY pause
AR_PLAY_HOLD quit
AR_NEXT seek 30
AR_NEXT_HOLD seek 120
AR_PREV seek -10
AR_PREV_HOLD seek -120
AR_MENU menu up
#AR_MENU menu cancel
AR_MENU_HOLD mute
AR_VUP volume 1
AR_VDOWN volume -1

##
## OSD Menu movement keys
##
## If you are using only the keyboard it is enough to define one command (like
## "menu up"), because then that single key will display the menu, which can
## then be navigated with the cursor keys and ENTER (defined in menu.conf).
##
## LIRC users should bind each "menu" command to a button on their remote.
##
## The set_menu command directly displays the (sub)menu specified as
## its argument. Usage should be self-explanatory (although not likely
## to be needed), after reading input.conf.
##

#MOUSE_BTN0 menu up
#y menu down
#y menu ok
#y menu cancel
#y menu hide
#y set_menu general_pref

##
## DVDNAV
## Requires dvdnav://
##

UP    {dvdnav} dvdnav up          # DVDNav UP
DOWN  {dvdnav} dvdnav down        # DVDNav DOWN
LEFT  {dvdnav} dvdnav left        # DVDNav LEFT
RIGHT {dvdnav} dvdnav right       # DVDNav RIGHT
ESC   {dvdnav} dvdnav menu        # DVDNav MENU
ENTER {dvdnav} dvdnav select      # DVDNav SELECT (ok)
BS    {dvdnav} dvdnav prev        # DVDNav PREVIOUS menu (in the order chapter->title->root)

AR_VUP    {dvdnav} dvdnav up      # DVDNav UP
AR_VDOWN  {dvdnav} dvdnav down    # DVDNav DOWN
AR_PREV   {dvdnav} dvdnav left    # DVDNav LEFT
AR_NEXT   {dvdnav} dvdnav right   # DVDNav RIGHT
AR_MENU   {dvdnav} dvdnav menu    # DVDNav MENU
AR_PLAY   {dvdnav} dvdnav select  # DVDNav SELECT (ok)

#? seek_chapter -1      # skip to previous dvd chapter
#? seek_chapter +1      #         next

##
## Advanced seek
## Uncomment the following lines to be able to seek to n% of the media with
## the Fx keys.
##
#F1 seek 10 1
#F2 seek 20 1
#F3 seek 30 1
#F4 seek 40 1
#F5 seek 50 1
#F6 seek 60 1
#F7 seek 70 1
#F8 seek 80 1
#F9 seek 90 1
```

Comment: Thanks, worked great for me. There's even a `run` command to execute shell commands.